# deploying Function to pre created Function App error : Web deployment task failed. ( Could not connect to the remote computer.)

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-deployment

I m deploying Azure Function to existing app. This app was created by admin and I m deploying to it for the first time.

It started publishing but later throws below error:

> Web deployment task failed. ( Could not connect to the remote computer
>   ("App URL"). Make sure that the remote computer name is correct and
>   that you are able to connect to that computer.

Not sure what is casing it. I use to deploy from VS by creating new function from VS but always faced this issue when function app was created from portal. Please help.

What I have tried:
If I try clicking Fun app url from portal I get this error page:

> This site can’t be reached
>   acncfuncintegrationtriggernonprod.aseint.cav.vic.gov.au’s server IP
>   address could not be found. DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

Comment: It seems that the function app has a custom domain which can't be resolved by DNS. You can try the original url of app to see whether the problem is related to the DNS. You can find the url in platform features>custom domains tab in portal, which is in the format of testfunction.azurewebsites.net.

Comment: Try to [troubleshooting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/publish/troubleshooting-web-deploy/troubleshooting-web-deploy-problems-with-visual-studio) Web Deploy problems with Visual Studio.